# How to switch off local storage on OwnCloud completely

Tags: amazon-s3, cloud, owncloud

I am using ownCloud for several users. So far all the data was stored on a machine drive. I want to store all the data on Amazon S3 (and none on the local machine).

How can I switch off local storage and make Amazon S3 folder default?

The search did not return any meaningful results other than instructions on how to simply add S3 storage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official ownCloud documentation provide the relevant configuration here:
https://doc.owncloud.com/server/9.1/admin_manual/enterprise_external_storage/s3_swift_as_primary_object_store_configuration.html#configuration

unfortunately I run the community edition where S3 is not supported so I haven't had yet a chance to test such instructions.